# Why "initializer-string for array of chars is too long" compiles fine in C & not in C++?

Tags: c++, c, string, gcc, g++

Following program compiles fine in C with  warnings but fails in compilation in C++. Why? What is the reason?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char a[5]="Hello";
    a[0]='y';
    puts(a);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("%c",a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

The warning:

```
Warning:[Error] initializer-string for array of chars is too long [-fpermissive] enabled by default
```

But if the program is compiled as C++ program then C++ compiler gives following error:

```
[Error] initializer-string for array of chars is too long [-fpermissive]
```

I am using GCC 4.8.1 compiler.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: it takes 6 characters to store Hello as an asciiz string

Comment: It gave you error on both compilers. Its just that on C++, the flag -fpermissive is lenient with the error.

Comment: You should code `char a[]="Hello";` to be sure to have a terminating 0-byte

Comment: @Milind: C is lenient. C++ isn't.

Comment: **In fact the premise of this question is incorrect.** Both times you were using a **C++** compiler but once it defaulted to compile with `-fpermissive`. The `-fpermissive` is not a **GCC C compiler option at all**!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Short answer: Because C and C++ are different languages with different rules.

Long answer: In both cases the reason is that the array is too small for the string literal. The literal consists of the five visible characters, with a zero terminator on the end, so the total size is 6.

In C, you're allowed to initialise an array with a string that's too long; extra characters are simply ignored:

> C99 6.7.8/14: An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive characters of the character string literal (including the terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array.

The compiler helpfully warns that the string is too large, since it almost certainly indicates an error; but it can't reject the code unless you tell it to treat warnings as errors.

In C++, the initialiser isn't allowed to be larger than the array:

> C++11 8.5.2/2: There shall not be more initializers than there are array elements.

so, for that language, the compiler should give an error.

In both languages, when you want a character array to be the right size for a string literal initialiser, you can leave the size out and the compiler will do the right thing.

```
char a[] = "hello";  // size deduced to be 6
```

Comment: Actually this is incorrect answer. The C standard does not allow the use of too long strings. What happens here is a constraint violation for [attempting to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p2). Notice that there is no length option for the successive characters of the string literal, unlike the "terminating null".

Comment: What Antti says. Also, the only corner case that C allows as per the quoted ("if there is room") remark is `char a[5] = "hello"; `. This is unfortunately allowed because of some historical reasons - related to skunky old "fixed-length" string formats in Unix. Even the C99 rationale embraces the practice. WG14 apparently feels that it is more important that some smelly code base from the 1970s still compiles than if new code written today is free from subtle bugs.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is in below line

```
char a[5]="Hello";
```

There is no space left to store the terminating null.

By default, `gcc` does not produce any errors for this case with `-fpermissive` option enabled. So, it *compiles fine* in `C`.

As per the requirement from the language standards,

- For`C99` standard, chapter 6.7.9, paragraph 14,

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF−8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array.

- For `C++11`, chapter 8.5.2, paragraph 2

> There shall not be more initializers than there are array elements.

So, the code compiles (with warnings) with `gcc`, produces error with `g++`.

Comment: But i have read that if programmer doesn't specify '\0' at end of string compiler will automatically add it & it is not very serious thing.

Comment: @meet: It's added to (or rather, included in) the string literal, yes. But it can't be added to the array of size 5, since that would require a sixth element.

Comment: @meet The space for null terminator is not there as we've defined the array to have `5` `char`s only.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: so it is allowed in C but not in C++ because C++ is a strongly typed language compared to C. right?

Comment: @meet: It's not really got anything to do with strong typing; just different rules in different languages. C is allowed to truncate the initialiser to fit the array; C++ isn't. See my answer for the rules themselves.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Sir, do you mind if I add those references to my answer, too?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: If you like. You don't need my permission to quote the language standard.

Comment: and stop with this "Sir" stuff ;p

Answer (score 4):

A valid string in C and C++ should have a `\0` terminator and in

```
char a[5]="Hello";
```

There is no space for null terminator and a is not a valid string.

So this might not be a error in C but you are bound to hit with issues when using in-built string functions like `strlen()` and family.

Comment: This is wrong, it is perfectly fine to initialize a non-null fixed-size character array with the contents of a string literal in C.

Answer (score 3):

Because "Hello" is 6 `char`s long and g++ without `-fpermissive`  won't initialise a 5 `char` array with it, but gcc will.

Comment: Why C will allow this?

Comment: @meet C always has and still does to remain backwards compatible.