# Get away with Initialize the char array without putting \0 at the end of string

Tags: c++, string

I am new to c++ language,recently, as I was taught that:

- we should put '\0' at the end of char array while doing initialization ,for example :

  `char x[6] = "hello"; //OK`
- However,if you do :

  `char x[5] = "hello";`

  Then this would raise the error :

  `initializer-string for array of chars is too long`

Everything goes as I expect until the experssion below does not raise the compile error...:

```
char x[5] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};
```

This really confuses me , So I would like to ask two questions :

1.Why doesn't expression `char x[5] = "hello";` raise error?

2.To my knowledge,the function `strlen()` would stop only if it finds '\0' to determine the lengh of char array,in this case,what would strlen(x) return?

Thanks!

Comment: First you say `char x[5] = "hello";`generates a compiler error, then you say it does not!?

Comment: @WernerHenze  He says he was taught that you need to leave space and if you don't there will be an error.  I have edited the question to make that clear.

Comment: gcc does raise an error: https://godbolt.org/z/jhenqs, and so do clang and msvc. What compiler with which command line settings did you use?

Comment: Without `'\0'`, the behavior of `strlen()` is undefined. The solution to all these issues is to use `std::string` instead of `char[]`

Comment: The `strlen` function will continue until it finds the terminator. If it's not inside the array then `strlen` will go out of bounds and you will have *undefined behavior*. Also, if you have a large array but a small but unterminated string in it then `strlen` will go outside the initialized part of the array, and check the uninitialized and *indeterminate* elements and you'll again have undefined behavior.

Comment: Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28434100/1468487)

Comment: Are you 100% positive this is C++ code that you are compiling? You tagged this "C++" but you said "c/c++" in your question, which makes it hard for us to be sure we understand what language you are asking about!

Comment: @WernerHenze i edit my answer,sorry for such big mistake.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I use c++ and compile with g++

Comment: @RemyLebeau I use g++ to compile and does not give any error off using :
    char x[5] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};
    strlen(x);
it retuens 10 .

Comment: @Pro_gram_mer assigning 5 individual chars to a 5-char array is perfectly legal. The compiler makes no assumptions about the array. Assigning a 6-char string literal to a 5-char array is not legal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string literal `"hello"` has six characters, because there's an implied nul terminator. So

```
char x[] = "hello";
```

defines an array of six `char`. That's almost always what you want, because the C-style string functions (`strlen`, `strcpy`, `strcat`, etc.) operate on C-style strings, which are, by definition, nul terminated.

But that doesn't mean that every array of `char` will be nul terminated.

```
char x[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
```

This defines an array of five `char`. Applying C-style string functions to this array will result in undefined behavior, because the array does not have a nul terminator.

You can do character-by-character initialization and create a valid C-style string by explicitly including the nul terminator:

```
char x[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
```

This defines an array of six `char` that holds a C-style string (i.e., a nul terminated sequence of characters).

The key here is to separate in your mind the general notion of an array of `char` from the more specific notion of an array of `char` that holds a C-style string. The latter is almost always what you want to do, but that doesn't mean that there is never a use for the former. It's just that the former is uncommon.

As an aside, in C you're allowed to elide the nul terminator:

```
char x[5] = "hello";
```

this is legal C, and it creates an array of 5 `char`, with no nul terminator. In C++ that's not legal.

Answer (score 2):

> Why doesn't expression `char x[5] = "hello";` raise an error?

This is not true. The appearance of an [error](https://godbolt.org/z/hbEK3W) is expected in this case.

> To my knowledge, the function `strlen()` would stop only if it finds `'\0'` to determine the length of the char array, in this case, what would `strlen(x)` return?

If you can run the code somehow, the program will undergo an undefined-behavior. That is, you will not get what you would expect. The `strlen()` will only stop counting when it finds a null-terminator, i.e. it may go outside the initialized part of the char array and access the uninitialized ones – it's where the UB is invoked.

Comment: I have modified the question,sorry for such a big mistake.