# I'm trying to understand strings in C

Tags: c

I'm reading about strings in C and I came across something I don't quite understand.

```
char str[3] = "Scaler.";
printf("%s", str);
```

Now they say the output would be

```
Sca
```

But wouldn't this behaviour be undefined as there is no place in the array to store a null terminator, and from what i've read all strings must have a null terminator appended at the end. Or when were initializing a char array with size less than the string literal is null terminator stored at the last index and if so wouldn't the output by `Sc`?

Comment: Yes, this is UB.

Comment: which is to say that "the output would be Sca" is wrong.  The output *might* be `Sca`.  Or it might be something like `Sca�3��` or anything.  Wherever you're reading about strings, idk if it's where you should be doing your learning. Your instincts seem to be right on though.  Additionally, compilers should throw a warning about this kind of code which you should *always* heed.

Comment: `char str[3] = "Scaler.";` is ok in C. [Why "initializer-string for array of chars is too long" compiles fine in C & not in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28434100). It's passing to `printf` that is UB.

Comment: When I tested it on my Linux system, the compiler gave me a warning about the character array size (/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/PrintString/main.c|6|warning: initializer-string for array of ‘char’ is too long|).  That is usually a big hint that at best there will be undefined behavior.  Depending upon the platform, various output could occur including a segmentation dump.  The key take-away would be to review compiler warnings.

Comment: @001 From the linked post, is that not a constraint violation for *attempting to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized.*? The answers in the linked post are not satisfactory.

Comment: Quick word on undefined behavior: "undefined" means that neither the compiler nor the runtime environment are required to handle the situation in any particular way; *any* result is possible (*including the result you expect*) and would be considered equally "correct" from the language definition's POV.  That result doesn't even have to be repeatable from build to build or even from run to run.  You *may* get a compiler diagnostic, or not.  Your code *may* crash outright, or not.  You *may* get the output `Sca`, or not.

Comment: @Harith: Reading 6.7.9, it seems that clause is meant to apply to brace-enclosed initializer lists, rather than string literals.  Given that under "Semantics" it talks about appending a nul "if there's room" also suggests the rules are slightly different for arrays initialized with a string literal rather than a brace-enclosed list.  But it could stand some clarification.

Comment: The initialization line is a constraint violation. Any compiler choosing to spit out an executable anyway has left all guarantees by standard C behind (6.7.9 §2), so anything can happen in the now "non C" application.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, printing with `%s` would invoke undefined behaviour, because without the null terminator, `str` is not a string.

If you want defined behaviour, you can print with the following which will limit it to printing three characters.

```
printf("%.3s\n", str);
```

You can also pass the length of `str` to `printf`.

```
printf("%.*s\n", (int)sizeof(str), str);
```

Comment: Thanks. I also read that the null character is automatically appended in initialization or is it only for full string literals which include the end " ?

Comment: If the array is long enough to include the null terminator, it will be included.

Answer (score 2):

It is undefined behaviour.

your `str` contains the first three characters from the string literal, but not null terminating character after that. When you try to use the `%s` format you invoke UB as you do not pass the C string.

It is only accidental that the next byte in memory was `0`. You can't predict how your program will behave.

Answer (score 2):

The declaration `char str[3] = "Scaler.";` by itself has undefined behavior, before even considering the `printf`.

C  2018 6.7.9 2 says “No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized.” But `"Scaler."` attempts to provide seven values for an array of three elements. The C standard requires an implementation to provide a diagnostic message for this but does not otherwise define the behavior, and so it is not defined.

Supposing the implementation does filling `str` with the characters `S`, `c`, and `a` and ignores the remaining characters, then the behavior of `printf("%s",str);`  is not defined because C 2018 7.21.6.1 says, about the `s` conversion:

> … If the precision is not specified or is greater than the size of the array, the array shall contain a null character…

Violation of this “shall” means the behavior is not defined by the C standard because C 2018 4 2 says:

> If a “shall” or “shall not” requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime-constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined…

> Now they say the output would be Sca

“They” are wrong. The output could be `Sca`, but it could be `Sca` followed by other characters, or the program could crash, or other behaviors could manifest.